# How can I test this method using Mockito?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a method with complex interaction between different objects that I would like to test using the Mockito framework. I would appreciate some guidelines. I know the code does not mean much.

Both `getInstance()` methods are static. I would like to mock obj3 and make the if statement to return true in the test.

```
public MyRequest getRequest(ObjectOne obj1, ObjectTwo obj2) {

    ObjectThree obj3 = FactoryOne.getInstance().getList().getObject(obj2.getId());


    if(FactoryTwo.getInstance().isFlagSet("flag")){
        ....
    }


    return new MyRequest(....);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the class that contains that method could have both factories as attributes and get them from a constructor that you could use to inject some mocks to mock the `getList()` and `isFlagSet(...)` .

Comment: "I know the code does not mean much"  in comparison with some others, it is not so bad.

Comment: Why mock `obj3` in the first place? Can't the test simply call `getRequest` with appropriate values for `obj1` and `obj2`, then check the returned value? As so many questions in this site, this one suffers from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Because obj3 might be constructed after access to db or cache.

Comment: Then let it. Trust me (as I write such tests nearly every day), investing on integration tests which access the db is much better, if you care about having good/useful tests, than trying to "fake it till you make it" (Kent Beck's expression).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method invoked to value the `obj3` variable is not straight testable.

The root cause is `getInstance()` that is a static method.

In fact, `FactoryOne.getInstance()` should be a dependency of the class under test and the returned object should be an interface

In this way, you can define a constructor that sets the dependency:

```
public MyClass(FooInterface foo){
   this.foo = foo;
}
```

And replace :

```
ObjectThree obj3 = FactoryOne.getInstance().getList().getObject(obj2.getId());
```

by :

```
ObjectThree obj3 = foo.getList().getObject(obj2.getId());
```

In the application code, you could invoke the constructor :

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(FactoryOne.getInstance().getList());
```

And in the test code, you could create a mock for the `Foo` interface, set it to the class under the test via the constructor :

```
Foo fooMock = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
MyClass myClassUnderTest = new MyClass(fooMock);
```

Then record a mock behavior for `getList()` to return another mocked object with the desired value for the invocation to `getObject()` in the test.

Comment: How do you know that it even makes sense to mock `obj3` in this case? And even if it needed to be mocked, it can perfectly well be done. So, either way, it's not justifiable to say the `getRequest` code is "not testable". Answers like this are not beneficial...

Comment: And on which point, you can affirm that it makes no sense ? The op want to know how mock its dependencies. I explain it to him. You could at least quote me correctly : "is not straight testable" doesn't mean "not testable".

Comment: Because the OP never describes what the actual problem is (it's a "XY question"), simply *assuming* for no stated reason that `FactoryOne` should be mocked. And the code *is* "straight testable" (I can write said test using two different mocking libraries if you want). But really, most likely any use of mocking here is a bad idea. I say this from many years, and many tests of experience, and having seen mocking getting misused/abused so many times...

Comment: The fact that the OP doesn't explain why a dependency should be mocked doesn't mean that it is not required. I had also many experience in test, but I don't conclude on zero information and only my bad experience as I mocked for bad reasons. Straight testable means: no powermock, no jmockit, etc... no bytecode manipulation at runtime.

Comment: I didn't say that mocking it is not required, I said we don't know that - although I guess it's really not needed. (Actually, the OP just commented the dependency involves some db access - which in itself is not a good reason to mock it, IMO.) You are showing irrational prejudice against tools other than your pet favorites. Sorry, but comments like "bytecode maniputation at runtime" [is bad] are just FUD (and illogical if you know what bytecode manipulation is).